# Run validation on input based on change of checkbox in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-forms, angular-validation

I am looping through an array of key values to create a list of checkboxes each with a sibling disabled input.  On check of each checkbox, the sibling input text field becomes enabled and is required. In this view there is a 'previous' and 'next' button and the 'next' button should be disabled if a user selects a checkbox and then does not enter anything in it's required sibling input.  I almost have this working, however the 'next' button should become disabled as soon as a user checks the box as this would mean they have not entered anything in the required text input.  Right now the 'next' button only becomes disabled if a user checks the checkbox, focuses on the sibling input and then leaves without entering.

My HTML...

```
<div *ngFor="let promotion of promotionOptions; let i = index">
    <div class="col-md-6 input-container radio-label">
        <mat-checkbox [checked]="!promotion.key" (change)="promotion.key = !promotion.key">
            {{ promotion.name }}
        </mat-checkbox>
    </div>
    <mat-input-container>
        <input matInput [disabled]="promotion.key" placeholder="Cost" name="promotionCost{{i}}" #promotionCost="ngModel" [ngModel]="" (keyup)="promotionCostInput($event.target.value)"
            [required]="!promotion.key" type="number">
        <div *ngIf="promotionCost.errors && (promotionCost.dirty || promotionCost.touched)" class="alert alert-danger cost-alert">
            <div [hidden]="!promotionCost.errors.required">Please enter the checked promotion's cost</div>
        </div>
    </mat-input-container>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="button-container">
    <button class="main-btn dark icon-left" (click)="updateStep(1)"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>Previous</button>
    <button class="main-btn icon-right" (click)="updateStep(3)" [disabled]="!promotionCostValid">Next<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
</div>
```

And the method I'm using in my .ts file for disabling the 'next' button:

```
promotionCostInput(value) {
    if (!value) {
      this.promotionCostValid = false;
    } else {
      this.promotionCostValid = true;
    }
  }
```

How can I validate the sibling input when a user checks the checkbox?

Comment: try this:  [disabled]="!promotionCostValid || promotionCost.errors"

Comment: Thanks for the comment Fateh, however I don't think I can use that outside of the ngFor loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the state of your `next` button is only updated when the `keyup` event is fired on any of your inputs. Besides, it is updated with only the value of **one** input but according to what you say, youwant to check that every inputs of your `ngFor` is filled.

I suggest you to store the value of your inputs in your model and to check that promotion cost is valid for all promotions any time the input change or a checkbox is checked.

```
<div *ngFor="let promotion of promotionOptions; let i = index">
  <div class="col-md-6 input-container radio-label">
    <mat-checkbox [checked]="!promotion.key" (change)="promotion.key = !promotion.key; checkPromotionCost();">
      {{ promotion.name }}
    </mat-checkbox>
  </div>
  <mat-input-container>
    <input
      matInput
      [disabled]="promotion.key"
      placeholder="Cost"
      name="promotionCost{{i}}"
      (keyup)="promotion.cost = $event.target.value; checkPromotionCost();"
      [required]="!promotion.key" type="number"
    >
    <div *ngIf="promotionCost.errors && (promotionCost.dirty || promotionCost.touched)" class="alert alert-danger cost-alert">
      <div [hidden]="!promotionCost.errors.required">
        Please enter the checked promotion's cost</div>
      </div>
  </mat-input-container>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="button-container">
  <button class="main-btn dark icon-left" (click)="updateStep(1)"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>Previous</button>
  <button class="main-btn icon-right" (click)="updateStep(3)" [disabled]="!promotionCostValid">Next<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
</div>
```

And in the controller:

```
checkPromotionCost() {
  this.promotionCostValid = true;
  this.promotionOptions.forEach(promotion => {
    if (promotion.key && promotion.cost === '') {
      this.promotionCostValid = false;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, etiennecrb.  But I don't understand where 'promostion.cost' comes from.  It is throwing an error from the Angular Cli that it does not exist and I have note declared it anywher.

Comment: I have just added it to your model, you can do something different if you prefer but it has to be stored somewhere.